# Disable type "promotion" (auto type assertions)

Tags: julia

In Julia, types are automatically "promoted", e.g.:

```
x = 8
y = 1.0
typeof(x)
typeof(y)
typeof(x + y)
```

Is it possible to disable this automatic type promotion? I am thing of something like implicitly 
`(x + y)::Int64`.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any way to add an integer to a float without first converting them to a common type. Every language that allows you to add numeric values of mixed type will do some kind of promotion first. In this case, if you want an `Int` result, you can convert the result with the `int` function: `int(8 + 1.0)`. Note that this converts floats to integers by rounding, not truncating as in many languages. You could also convert `1.0` to an `Int` before adding, in which case you would be adding two integers and you'd get an integer.

Comment: Thanks for tour answer. I agree with what you write and am aware of this. I just wondered if there was any way to avoid this to obtain type stability without making a lot of type assertions manually and doing post static analysis.

Comment: According to John Myles White this feature is currently being debated ( https://twitter.com/mikldk/status/447116240285618176 ).